# Get result based on property of another document from one document in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two documents -

```
const taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    leadId: { type: String, default: '' },
    customer_name: { type: String, default: '' }
})

const leadSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Id: { type: String, default: "" },
  associate_status: { type: Boolean, default: false },
})
```

I want to run a query on tasks such that I get all the leads where associate status is true.

`LeadId` in task schema is the same as `Id` in the lead schema.

I tried this -

```
  const report = await taskModel.aggregate([
   { $lookup: {
      from: 'leads',
      let: { leadId: '$leadId' },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: ['$Id', '$$leadId'],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
      as: 'leaditems',
    },
  }
  { $unwind: '$leaditems' },
  { $match: { leaditems.associate_status: true}}
 ])
```

But since I have a large number of documents (more than 200k leads and 100k tasks, and these numbers will keep on growing), the query sometimes runs after 9 to 10 seconds and sometimes doesn't runs at all. I am looking for a more optimized approach or any other implementation that will make this work.

Update:

I tried this as well but no improvement -

```
const report = await taskModel.aggregate([
       { $lookup: {
          from: 'leads',
          let: { leadId: '$leadId' },
          pipeline: [
            {
              $match: {
                $expr: {
                  $and: [
                   {
                     $eq: ['$Id', '$$leadId'],
                   },
                   {
                     $eq: ['$associate_status', true],
                   },
                 ],
               },
              },
            },
          ],
          as: 'leaditems',
        },
      }
     ])
```

Comment: Please avoid using Indian words like "lahk". People aren't going to understand you.

Comment: you created the index in lookup fields? thats the most important, also to use the index in with $expr in lookup pipeline, you need Mongodb 5, what version do you have? if you have  < Mongodb 5, use a simple equality lookup

Comment: @JamesZ Sure, I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @Takis_ The reason I did not create an index was, these parameters ( properties of leads which I need to look for ) will increase in the future, so is creating an index for every parameter that needed to be looked for a good practice? Also, I am using MongoDB 4.4.9 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the index in `$exp` inside a lookup pipeline you need MongoDB 5.
MongoDB 4.4.9 will not use the index and query will be slow.

- create the indexes in leads and Id, its expected to be much faster
  (index helps if it has good selectivity, if select small percentage of the documents, an index that will return 90% of documents can make things worse)(if you add many values on leadId index will be updated also, it can cost, but the benefits most of the times are much more)
- replace with a simple equality `$lookup`
- Also if you dont really need the `$unwind` and you prefer your data in array you can use `$filter`

```js
const report = await taskModel.aggregate([
       { $lookup: {
          from: 'leads',
          localField: "leadId",
          foreignField: "Id",
          as : "leaditems"
       },
       { $unwind: '$leaditems' },
       { $match: { leaditems.associate_status: true}}       
     ])
```

If possible benchmark it after you do those and send some feedback.

Comment: After creating an index against 'leadId' and 'Id', the query was working inside 1 second. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Put `$match` condition in `$lookup` `pipeline` or even try to put it before `$lookup`.

Set `index` on both associated id.

Maybe your service has a 10 second database connection constraint, try to make it longer.

Comment: I have tried putting the match conditions inside the lookup, but it still doesn't work. I have checked the service constraint too, it is up to 60 seconds. If my query doesn't perform within 60 seconds, then I guess it's of no use.